# Deleting duplicated data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I found a lot of duplicated data in my SQL Server with this query

```
SELECT
    [MærkeID], [Model], [Årgang], [Motor Type], [Krydsmålet],
    [Centerhul], [Bolter], [Dæk], [Fælge], [ET], [vendor], COUNT(*)
FROM
    Data.Hjuldata   
GROUP BY
    [MærkeID], [Model], [Årgang], [Motor Type], [Krydsmålet],
    [Centerhul], [Bolter], [Dæk], [Fælge], [ET], [vendor]
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

[image]

Is there a way to delete them so there is only 1 record instead of 2 of the same?

Comment: What will be the deletion criteria?

Comment: not sure what you mean with criteria but i want it so there is just 1 of each record instead of 2 of the exact same as you can see in my no column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT
     *
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                           [MærkeID]
                          ,[Model]
                          ,[Årgang]
                          ,[Motor Type]
                          ,[Krydsmålet]
                          ,[Centerhul]
                          ,[Bolter]
                          ,[Dæk]
                          ,[Fælge]
                          ,[ET]
                          ,[vendor] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
FROM Data.Hjuldata )
DELETE FROM X 
WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: I was almost there :(